# Problem in calculating growth rate in R - result all 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df in which there are ids for different years and a variable CI that is an id-year specific indicator ranging between 0 and 1.

Here is a sample of how my data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(c("002", "004"), each = 6),
  years = rep(c(1920, 1921, 1922, 1923, 1924, 1925), times = 2),
  CI = c(0.3023104860, 0.3184651329, 0.3173958777, 0.2833701369, 0.2858395440, 0.2436667622,
         0.5499678083, 0.5746689830, 0.5820752615, 0.5941080701, 0.6281830146, 0.6198584776)
)
```

I want to calculate the growth rate of this indicator for each id.

It should be rather straighforward but I cannot get the right result and also cannot find the answer in possibly related posts.

The code I tried is:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator_growth = (CI - (lag(CI)/lag(CI)))
```

The problem is that the variable indicator_growth is added to the df, but it contains only 0 values.

Ps: the time series have some gaps for some of the ids (not all ids have data on CI for all years) but I tried already to calculate the same on only one id that has data for all the years and I still get only 0s.

Do you know why this is happening and how to get the actual growth rates? Can you also provide a solution for considering the gaps in the time series in such a way that I get the growth rate between the closest available years if the gap is < 3 years and NA values if larger?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide data. Are you calculating `1 - 1/1`?

Comment: The actual data is very long so I can't provide it. But the CI variable ranges between 0 and 1, and the maximum value 1 is not often registered. I tried calculating manually and I can get reasonable numbers for the growth rate, so no, the problem is not that I am calculating `1-1/1`

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible to help without reproducible data, and the question may be closed due to lack of reproducibility. Even though your dat are long, you can provide sample data. Either something like `dput(df[1:25,])` or create your own sample data that reproduces the problem, ie `df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = letters[1:10])` - but without *something*, its only going to be speculation. Just trying to help you get the help you need on here, and not have your question closed. Good luck!

Comment: I added a piece of code that creates a sample df, that has same structure and values of my actual data. Thank you for the kind comment.

Comment: Thanks for editing! In your `dplyr` pipe, you are missing a `)` - it should be `mutate(...lag(CI))))` not `mutate(...lag(CI)))` - when I add that, I get non-zero numbers using your sample data. Is that the problem? Also, isn't `lag(CI) / lag(CI)` always equal to 1? If I run `mutate(CI - 1)` I get the same values (except for the first value of the group, which returns `NA` with `lag()`)?

Comment: Thank you for detecting this! Indeed I tried and I get the non-zero values after adding a `)`, not the right ones though. The first growth rate should be (0.3184651329 - 0.3023104860)/0.3023104860 = 0.05343726946 . However, I get -0.6976895140 ...

Comment: I think I figured out where is the problem, but I do not understand how to solve it. The lag function is not working properly. If I do ```df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(CI_lagged = lag(CI))``` the CI_lagged is not lagged, but it contains exactly the time series as CI (which explains why I was getting 0s before). Do you know why this may happen?

Comment: Use `lead()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation I think you are looking for `lead` instead of `lag` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(indicator_growth = (lead(CI) - CI)/lead(CI), .by = id)


#    id years        CI indicator_growth
#1  002  1920 0.3023105      0.050726580
#2  002  1921 0.3184651     -0.003368838
#3  002  1922 0.3173959     -0.120075253
#4  002  1923 0.2833701      0.008639137
#5  002  1924 0.2858395     -0.173075644
#6  002  1925 0.2436668               NA
#7  004  1920 0.5499678      0.042983309
#8  004  1921 0.5746690      0.012723919
#9  004  1922 0.5820753      0.020253569
#10 004  1923 0.5941081      0.054243658
#11 004  1924 0.6281830     -0.013429738
#12 004  1925 0.6198585               NA
```

Comment: Your code `df %>% mutate(indicator_growth = (lead(CI) - CI)/lead(CI), .by = id)` Does not work for me. I get:  `Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame.` If I modify it in this way: `df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator_growth = (lead(CI) - CI)/lead(CI)) ` . I still get an error: `Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `indicator_growth = (lead(CI) - CI)/lead(CI)`.
ℹ In group 1: `id = "002"`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'lead' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Comment: I think the function `lead` is masked in your environment. Try using `dplyr::lead` instead of just `lead`.

Comment: This was the problem indeed! I think in my context the right thing to do is to use `lag` instead of `lead`, but once I specify the dplyr package in front of lag it works well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is wrong. Also you have missed one closing bracket `)` which I have corrected:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(indicator_growth = (CI - (lag(CI)/lag(CI))))
```

You should change your code to `(CI - lag(CI)) / lag(CI)` instead of `(CI - (lag(CI)/lag(CI)))`, which calculates incorrect growth rate.

Better use:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(indicator_growth = (CI - lag(CI)) / lag(CI))
```

Also, for your second requirement, one work around is to use the `ifelse()` function to check if the time gap is less than 3 years and calculate the growth rate accordingly.

here it is how:

```
df <- df %>%
    arrange(id, years) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(timeGap = years - lag(years),
           indicator_growth = ifelse(timeGap < 3, (CI - lag(CI)) / lag(CI), NA)) %>% select(-timeGap)
```

Check if this helps...

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code, I think you are right. However, I tried this: ```df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(indicator_growth = (CI - lag(CI)) / lag(CI))``` and I still get 0 values in the indicator_growth column. The reason is that the function lag(CI) is not working properly, as I explained above. And using `lead` instead is also returning an error

Comment: can you please share some more data.. because on the data that you provided, codes in both answers (from me and Ronak) seemed to work...

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that `lead` and `lag` were masked in my environment hence not working properly

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator_growth = (CI - dplyr::lag(CI)) / dplyr::lag(CI))
```

this code is the one that calculated it correctly.

Thank you all very much for your help!!!